# Why does a regex entity have priority in Dialogflow CX?

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-cx

I am establishing two entities in my Dialogflow CX agent:

- the first one, called "**id**" contains some numeric IDs that exist in my domain: e.g. 29042, 29145, 28248, ...
- the second one, "**wrongId**", is defined by a regex that is supposed to capture all numeric sequences similar to the previous entities: \d{5,6}

These two entities are used in different phrases of the same intent.

The goal is to make the agent behavior in a certain way if the numeric ID inserted by the user exists; otherwise, the agent will say that such ID does not exist. For this purpose, I created two different routes. The first one is activated when the first entity is matched; the second one is activated when the regex entity is matched.

Since routes are evaluated in the order they are presented, I would expect that if the user inserted a valid ID, the first route would be activated; if the user inserted an ID that does not exist, then the first route would be discarded and the second one will be activated.

However, I noticed that the second route is always activated, as if the regex entity is always preferred to the regular one when Dialogflow parses the entities in an intent.

Can anyone confirm this behavior, or otherwise point to any mistake I am making?

Comment: Have you checked the confidence score?.  CX scores each intent match and chooses the one with the highest score.  However, the [Google docs](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/intent#Intent-matching) don't mention what happens when more than one matches have the same score.

Comment: Hi, does the score mechanism also work for different entities in the same intent? Because in my case, it's not a matter of assigning a score to two different intents, but rather to assign a score to one entity or the other of the same intent

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question the first time.  The confidence score is a measure of how certain CX is that the intent matched regardless of the parameters in the phrase. So, if two routes are configured with the same intent, then the confidence score will be the same for both, and the 2nd route will always win because, as you said, they're evaluated in order.

Instead of two separate routes, consider using one route and implementing a [condition](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/condition) or a webhook to choose the transition based on the parameter match.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description above, the entity "id" and the entity "wrongId" have overlapping values. Specifically, regular expression `\d{5,6}` can match all examples you provided for the entity "id".

Here's a screenshot from https://regex101.com/:

[image: regex matches 29042]

That is, when you input a correct id, either one or the other entity can be matched.

Using entities with competing values is against [agent design best practices](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/agent-design#avoid-similar-entity). Avoiding to use conflicting (also referred to as competing or ambiguous) training data when designing your agent will help you avoid conflicts at runtime.

If you have a small number of correct id's, you could add them as [entity exclusions](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/entity-options#exclusion) to the "wrongId" entity.

Another approach could be to match both correct and wrong id's with the same (broader) entity and validate collected values against your id's database in the backend.

Comment: Hi Svetlana! Yes, the two entities have overlapping values by design. They are part of the same group of IDs, only a portion is valid while the other one is not. In that sense, your suggestions to validate them against an external database is probably the most correct one. I was just wandering if there's a way to determine how DF will resolve ambiguities, especially since here the two entitites are designed differently (one is a series of strings, the other is a regexp). Thanks anyway!